# Why show a Visit button for a private beta I am not a part of?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, action-buttons

I'm logged into Area51, and can see which sites I'm a part of. All good and well, but when I go onto the page of a site that is in private beta, I still see the button inviting me to visit the site. Of course, once I do so I see a page telling me to come back when the site goes into public beta.

If you know which sites I am committed to/following/active in private beta, etc. then why not use that information to hide a private beta button?

Comment: Most likely this is a bug

Comment: Can a post be both a [bug] and a [feature-request]? Surely it should be one or the other?

Comment: @Andy: FWIW, the `[bug]` tag was added by not-the-OP.  But I think it's okay; I read it as "I think this is a bug that needs to be fixed.  If you disagree, but also don't consider it 'by design,' please change it."

Comment: I must say I didn't initially consider it a bug, but in retrospect you may be right. Can/Should I remove the [feature-request] tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We no longer show the private beta link button unless you previously *committed* to the site that is now in private beta.